# Check whether a field is specified in an object in Apex

Tags: apex, soql

Example:

```
public static String doStuff(Custom_Object__c record){
    String message = record.Custom_Field__c;
    return message;
}
```

How would you check that `Custom_Field__c` is on that record? I am currently getting `SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field: Custom_Object__c.Custom_Field__c`

Is `try-catch` the only option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`isSet`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_isSet) method to determine if a field is populated before trying to access it:

```
String message = '';
if(record.isSet(fieldName)) {
  message = (String)record.get(fieldName);
}
return message;
```

You can use either a String or a sObjectField token.

Comment: Just checked the docs and found this too! How new is it do you know?

Comment: That is brilliant.

Comment: @fred I updated the verbiage to make the answer more timeless, but this was one of many new things we got in the Summer 23 release. So it's like a month or so at this point, depending on when you were upgraded.

Comment: @JefersonChaves Your answer was also perfectly valid, FWIW. I'd leave it as an alternative to this solution, as it may be helpful in some cases.

Comment: I agree. I didn't know about `getPopulatedFieldsAsMap` either

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, but this new method `isSet` fits more naturally and allows the usage of field token.

Comment: It might be worth adding reference to isSet from the docs.

Comment: @JefersonChaves That's fair. I've added a link.

Answer (score 4):

It depends; most of the time this exception is a good thing meaning you should update the code path and query.

But if you want to go to dynamic code, you can leverage [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap):

```
public static String doStuff(Custom_Object__c record){
    Map<String, Object> fieldsToValue = record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();

    String customFieldValue = (String) fieldsToValue.get('Custom_Field__c');
    Boolean isEmpty = String.isEmpty(customFieldValue);

    String message = customFieldValue;
    return message;
}
```